Classes disappeared in Gmail in RSS campaign
My problem is that I have designed email in an RSS campaign when I send this email to Outlook or yahoo it works fine there either on desktop or mobile. But when I sent this in Gmail the classes disappeared and with this issue, my design got broken.
I tried to apply simple class names complex class names used but nothing worked for me.
